# How to Make Android phone Slave Display Raspberry Pi 3b?

Tags: oneplus-3, secondary-display

I would like to have an extra display always with me. The only thing which I have most often with me is my Phone with CM13. 
Phone

- *Oneplus 3* and its USB Type C connection may be suitable for the task.
- Software: make CM13 software understand that I want to use it as a slave for other microprocessor.

Client RP3b

- There is HDMI signal from RP3b. I can use usbC-to-HDMI adapter but not sure if it is needed because the data rate is sufficient in USB-C itself.

Phone: Oneplus 3
System: Cyanogenmod 13 Stable
Phones failed: Samsung Galaxy S4 gt-i9506

Phone: Oneplus 3T
OS: Oreo 8.0

Comment: You could check the [Raspberry Pi](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_various#group_723) section of my remote-control-app lists for one. Maybe there's already a fitting app for it. Not sure if a "native solution" (not requiring a specific app) does exist.

Comment: @Izzy I got today a new phone, Oneplus 3. Can you use Usb-C connection for the task now?

Comment: No idea, sorry – first, I have no USB-C device, and second no Raspi.

Answer (score 0):

This feature needs to be supported by the phone manufacturer. 
The software is not a challenge after that. 
I know no phone which has such a feature at the moment.